# Extend widgets for common input fields in apostrophe cms

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am creating multiple widgets in apostrophe 2.x which work fine. Now I want to structure and organise them properly.
Most of my modules have an option for changing from content-width to browser-width. I am trying to generalise this function without putting the code in every module.

For example in my layout-widget/index.js I have this:

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Layout',
  addFields: [{
    name: 'size',
    label: 'Modulbreite',
    type: 'select',
    choices: [{
        label: 'Content width',
        value: 'content-width'
      },
      {
        label: 'Full width',
        value: 'full-width'
      }
    ],
    required: true
  }]
};
```

And now I want to create other widgets that get individual configuration options as well as this selection by extending this general module configuration.
File: test-widget/index.js

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'layout-widgets',
  label: 'Test',
  addFields: [{
      name: 'headline',
      label: 'Headline',
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    {
      name: 'content',
      label: 'Add Element',
      type: 'area',
      options: {
        widgets: {
          'fact': {},
          'text': {}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

But currently I do not see the option for size in my CMS for the test widget. I only see the options directly defined in the test module. Is this even possible or must I insert the size select into every module itself?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, you just need to write 'layout-widgets/index.js' with this intention in mind. That module can't just set addFields because that will be overridden by the modules that extend it. Instead, it must use a `beforeConstruct` function to manipulate `addFields`. Here is an example from the `apostrophe-pieces` module:

```
beforeConstruct: function(self, options) {
  options.addFields = [
    {
      type: 'boolean',
      name: 'published',
      label: 'Published',
      def: false
    }
  ].concat(options.addFields || []);
}
```

`beforeConstruct` should be at the same level as `construct`, i.e. not nested inside it.

Comment: Oh that is awesome! Thanks for the explanation. @Tom

Comment: This works like a charm. Just tested it. Significantly reduces the length of my index.js files :). Awesome work, Thank you